# Mac OS X Terminal error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode-5.1.1.app'

Tags: xcode, terminal, directory, theos

I'm trying to setup and install theos in my Mac OS X El Capitan with terminal. I'm following iPhoneDevWiki (http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup) and doing every single step correctly, I've done it multiple times but everytime I get this little error. I already have all dependencies, the problem comes when I do the following command:

```
git clone git://git.saurik.com/ldid.git
fatal: destination path 'ldid' already exists and is not an empty directory.
cd ldid
git submodule update --init
./make.sh
Password:
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode-5.1.1.app
```

I have put my password and it did show the error. I have already tried the following commands:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcode-select -s </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer>
```

This second one actually leads me to an error of "newline" or something like that.
My xcode version is not 5.1.1, I don't even know why my Terminal is saying Xcode.app is Xcode-5.1.1!

```
 xcode-select -v
 xcode-select version 2343.
```

I have already tried to put the command:

```
xcode-select -p
```

The output is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

So, if that is the output, why it is saying my developer directory is "/Applications/Xcode-5.1.1.app" ?

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Open `make.sh` file inside `ldid` folder. In line 16 edit the path to:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Then run `./make.sh` again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your Xcode app to Xcode-5.1.1 in the Applications folder.  That worked for me.